# KVO: How to identify specific UILabel using context?

Tags: swift, key-value-observing

If you add a key-value observer to multiple `UILabels` in the same object, how can you identify them specifically in the KVO context?

Add KVOs to two `UILabels`:

```
someLabel.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "text", options: [.old, .new], context: nil)

someOtherLabel.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "text", options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
```

KVO handler:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    if change?[.oldKey] as! String != change?[.newKey] as! String {

        // do something

    }

}
```

Comment: You can use the parameter object (which is the observed object).

Comment: (I don't know why Willeke deleted their answer, which was technically correct: use `object` to determine which one was observed.) But… never do this. If you're observing a `UILabel` you're doing something deeply wrong. Labels are views. You should not use views to drive logic. You should be observing whatever Model object is used to populate the view.

Comment: @RobNapier from a purely nuts and bolts perspective, what's the technical drawback to observing a `UILabel`? Is it not just one object observing another?

Comment: I don't know what you mean here by "nuts and bolts perspective." There is no technical drawback, any more than there is a technical drawback to storing all data in mutable global variables. It completely "works." The practical drawback is the same: it makes a program more difficult to reason about and modify. Model information should be stored in model objects, and views should display model objects. If something is watching the view's model, control is flowing in the wrong direction for an MVC system like Cocoa.

Comment: An an example of how it makes a program more difficult to reason about, it is extremely common for bugs to be introduced due to view-lifecycle issues. Developers commonly forget that views are not loaded until fairly late in the view controller's life, and may (or may not!) be unloaded when the view controller leaves the screen. I have regularly encountered bugs due to people expecting views to be available prior to viewDidLoad (and in the old viewDidUnload days, after viewDidUnload).

Comment: My only pushback would be to challenge that it should never be done and that it must mean something is deeply wrong. It's a very particular use case where I simply could not find an alternative (which may or may not exist). And all the observer does is generate haptic feedback. I would actually be curious to know if an alternative exists as I could not find one.